# Show all Bootstrap Carousel Slides at once using CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Under a certain condition I am adding a class to my bootstrap carousel. When this class is added I would like to change the CSS so that all images within the carousel are displayed at once potentially with a horizontal scrollbar. Is there an easy way to achieve this display?

I know there is a Javascript approach where you can iterate through items and append them to one another to show multiple slides on one screen but I thought that a CSS approach would be cleaner.

Edit:
Here is the code I'm using to generate the carousel:

```
<div class="container vcenter">
<br>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        @{
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (var carouselSlide in Model.Children)
            {
                if (counter == 0)
                {
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="@counter"></li>
                }
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        @{
            counter = 0;
            foreach (var carouselSlide in @Model.Children)
            {
                if (counter == 0)
                {
                    <div class="item active">
                            @RenderImage(carouselSlide, x => x.Image, isEditable: true)
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="item">
                        @RenderImage(carouselSlide, x => x.Image, isEditable: true)
                    </div>
                }
                counter += 1;
            }            }
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code - You can probably achieve this by removing some of the bootstrap carousel classes.

Comment: `.carousel.slide` - it's the only class on the slide wrapper to remove.

Comment: I found that if I mark all items as active they show up all at once vertically. Ideally they would display next to each other horizontally with scrolling. Actually, maybe I can change their wrappers into inline block elements and add scrolling to the parent div

Comment: Thanks for the help! It looks like it's coming together now. I gave my carousel overflow-x: scroll. Then I made each carousel item active and changed their display to inline block and removed all of my other css formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of the CSS class for your issue.

I've add small script to pause the carousel. If you remove the `carousel slide` classes, then this script is not needed.

[image: the result]

https://codepen.io/glebkema/full/xOJgKa

```js
$( window ).load( function() {
  $('.abreast').carousel('pause');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

/* The heart of the matter */
.abreast .carousel-inner {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.abreast .item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 6px 4px 0 0;
}
.abreast .carousel-control, 
.abreast .carousel-indicators {
  display: none;
}

/* Make the images responsive. */
.carousel-inner img {
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>With the <span class="label label-default">.abreast</span> class</h3>

  <div id="carousel-1" class="carousel slide abreast" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300/c69/f9c/?text=1" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300/9c6/cf9/?text=2" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300/69c/9cf/?text=3" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
  </div>


  <h3>Without the <span class="label label-default">.abreast</span> class</h3>

  <div id="carousel-2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300/c69/f9c/?text=1" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300/9c6/cf9/?text=2" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300/69c/9cf/?text=3" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-2" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-2" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```